# Get an element before a string with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup to search a website for a set of integer values and produce a list of these, matched to names. However, the problem I'm having is that the website uses some very vague class names for the elements I need ("list-item") that are reproduced in other elements, which I don't want to grab. So far my code looks like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = "http://beautifulnumberssite.com/"
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = bs(html)

names = soup.findAll("h1", class_="th1")
stats = soup.findAll("li", class_="list-item")

print(names, stats)
```

However, this is also returning a whole bunch of stuff I don't want. Is there a way I make it so Beautiful Soup only returns the contents of elements which are followed by a certain string? So, if the web-page contains a section that's like:

```
<li class='list-item'>
<strong>65</strong>
Important Values
</li>
<li class='list-item'>
<strong>49</strong>
Useless Values
</li>
```

I would like to be able to set Beautiful Soup/Python to parse for a string like "Important Values" and get the element directly before it (ignoring any line breaks or white-space), or better yet the value contained within the element. So in this case Beautiful Soup would either print:

```
<strong>65</strong>
```

or, more preferably, just:

```
65
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Of course, it's your choice which answer to accept, but if you go with what is currently accepted, you'd be overcomplicating the problem. Why iterate over all list items if you can get to the desired value directly? Plus, why get the `contents` list if you can get the text and convert it to `int` directly?

Comment: Good point. I'll have a look over the new answer and work out which one is best for me.  Thanks for taking the time to give an additional answer. Much appreciated. I'm certain I would upvote both if I were currently able. But you're also correct that I should take the time to look over the new one properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate on your class elements and check if their contents match your important string :

```
for listItem in soup.findAll('li', class_='list-item'):
    if listItem.decode_contents(formatter="html").find('Important Values') != -1:
        print(listItem.find('strong').contents)
```

Comment: This is good, thank you, but for some reason it's outputting `[u'65']` instead of the expected `['65']`. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: I think it's due to it being a unicode string that's how python2.7 manages them.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to be able to set Beautiful Soup/Python to parse for a string like "Important Values" and get the element directly before it (ignoring any line breaks or white-space), or better yet the value contained within the element

`BeautifulSoup` is quite flexible in terms of locating elements. There are all sorts of techniques to find elements in the HTML. In this case, we can find the "Important Values" text node and find the [preceding `strong` element](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
important_values = int(soup.find(text=lambda text: text and text.strip() == 'Important Values').find_previous_sibling("strong").get_text())
print(important_values)  # prints 65
```

Or, we can create a ["search function"](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) and check for the `strong` element name and the next text sibling node to be "Important Values":

```
def search_function(tag):
    is_strong = tag.name == "strong"
    is_important = tag.next_sibling and tag.next_sibling.strip() == 'Important Values'
    return is_strong and is_important

important_values = int(soup.find(search_function).get_text())
print(important_values)  # prints 65
```

Comment: On further testing I have found that this solutions errors out when there are no values present, or when the present values are not of the expected type.