# Get an HTML element based on the element before with Beautiful Soup (EPA website)

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to print the "Civil Penalty" section of EPA settlements like https://www.epa.gov/enforcement/chevron-settlement-information-sheet or https://www.epa.gov/enforcement/ngl-crude-logistics-llc-clean-air-act-settlement

Out of the following HTML source

```
<h2 id="civil">Civil Penalty</h2>
<p>Chevron U.S.A. will pay a $2.95 million civil penalty, of which $2,492,750 will be paid to the United States and $457,250 to the State of Mississippi.</p>
```

I would like to get *Chevron U.S.A. will pay a $2.95 million civil penalty ...*

This structure is the same for all settlement factsheets.

```
<h2 id="civil">Civil Penalty</h2>
<p>NGL will pay a civil penalty of $25 million. The penalty is based, in part, on the company’s limited ability to pay a larger penalty.</p>
```

I've found similarities to [Get an element before a string with Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400866/get-an-element-before-a-string-with-beautiful-soup) – but this is not fully identical to my question.

Here is my code skeleton:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

for i in ['chevron-settlement-information-sheet', 'ngl-crude-logistics-llc-clean-air-act-settlement', 'derive-systems-clean-air-act-settlement']:

    page = requests.get("https://www.epa.gov/enforcement/"+i)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    data = []

    for result in soup.find_all('h2', id='civil'):
        data.append(result)

print(data)
```

How can I print the `<p>` section directly following a `<h2 id="civil">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason you may not have been getting the results you were looking for is you were adding `/history` to the URL, which leads to a [404 error page](https://www.epa.gov/enforcement/chevron-settlement-information-sheet/history). If you remove that part and then use `findNext('p')` to get the next paragraph element on the page after the `<h2 id="civil">` element, you will get the expected result:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for url in ['chevron-settlement-information-sheet', 'ngl-crude-logistics-llc-clean-air-act-settlement', 'derive-systems-clean-air-act-settlement']:

    page = requests.get("https://www.epa.gov/enforcement/" + url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    result = soup.find('h2', {'id': 'civil'}).findNext('p')
    print(result.text)
```

This prints out:

```
Chevron U.S.A. will pay a $2.95 million civil penalty, of which $2,492,750 will be paid to the United States and $457,250 to the State of Mississippi.
NGL will pay a civil penalty of $25 million. The penalty is based, in part, on the company’s limited ability to pay a larger penalty.
Derive will pay a civil penalty of $300,000, as the company has limited financial ability to pay a higher penalty.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the sibling selector, `+`.

```
p=soup.select('#civil + p')
print(p[0].getText())
```

This will select only the `p` element that is the very next sibling of the `#civil` element.